# Sending e-mail via PHP, on behalf of someone else

Tags: php, email, spam, dkim, spf

I would like to create a form that allows users to contact our local city council. I want to make it easy, so they can just fill out the form and send it. I am just not 100% sure how this would work in regards to spam filtering.

1. I know how to send e-mail through php usind sendmail, and also via Google Apps smtp server.
2. Mail from our domain has both SPF and DKIM applied, and it is working correctly

What I'm wondering is if someone fills out the form and we use their e-mail address in the from field will it be blocked as spam?

I am not sure how the verification that we have set up to verify mail from our domain will affect mail sent from our server, with a from address that has a different domain.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, to clarify, I would like to be able for the recipient to see that the message was from the person that sent it, not our website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will most likely be treated as spam as your local mailserver will not feel responsible for sending mail from a domain it does not serve. You can however use a default `from` address (like `noreply@example.com` - just use some domain your mailserver is responsible for) and use the `reply-to` field for the email address of your user.

Comment: But then in that case the recipients would see all of the messages as coming from the same address. So, for example, say if overnight 20 people used the form to send a message, when the recipient checked their e-mail in the morning they'd see 20 messages all from the same address.

Also, not saying that it WOULD happen, but since the messages are being sent to city councilors they could easily block the noreply address to avoid getting the messages. However, this should not happen as the messages are being sent by city residents. May not happen, but would like to make sure.