# PHP mail() - Different domain emails for From and reply-to

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I want users on my website to use php mail() to send emails from my website domain. I would like users to get replies on their personal email address which will not be my domain email it might be gmail, hotmail or any other. When I do so, the email recipients get a phishing warning in gmail.

How can I set headers in php mail() so different sender and reply-to emails do not make gmail and other services tag the email as spam or phishing.

Comment: basically your lying about the source of the email, hence the warning, its hard to get around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204050/sending-e-mail-via-php-on-behalf-of-someone-else

Answer (score 0):

Your recipients are getting a pishing warning because your emails are not passing SPF checks. That simply means that the `from` domain you are using is not authorizing your server to send mail on its behalf.

Try using PHPmailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

You can use it to set a separate from address as well as a specific reply to address

```
$mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@email.com', 'Reply to name');
$mail->SetFrom('mailbox@email.com', 'Mailbox name');
```

That being said.  The `SetFrom` address is an address that must pass SPF and preferably DKIM checks to be **NOT** marked as **SPAM or PISHED**.  This address is recognized as the **BOUNCE** address where all the bounced emails will be returned to.  Not having a valid address may possibly disrupt future deliveries.

The `AddReplyTo` address will be loaded when the reply button is clicked by the recipient.  Keep in mind that even though the message may pass SPF there are many **SPAM filters** that will potentially mark the message as spam.

Comment: as any SPF record would have to beset by the sending user, there is not a lot the OP can actually do here. simply using phpmailer will make no difference

Comment: Separating a `from address` from a `reply to` address will enable SPF checks.  And therefore solve the requested problem.  The solution is not to use PHPmailer. It is the distinct separation of the settings.

Comment: but the SPF record needs to be set on the senders domain

Comment: so where is a solution that will work for the OP in this "answer" ?

Comment: @nogad .  Please read above solution `That being said. The SetFrom address is an address that must pass SPF and preferably DKIM checks to be NOT marked as SPAM or PISHED. `  If the **setFrom** is the sending servers address.  A separate **replyTo** address can be set which does not have to pass a SPF check.

Comment: Here I am using 3 different info when using phpmailer,     `$mail->Sender  = $resultGroup->email;  //the sender domain email.
 $mail->SetFrom($senderEmail, $senderName); //any email of sender like gmail, hotmail
 $mail->AddReplyTo($replyEmail, $replyName);//any email` Will this header be marked as phishing too?

Comment: Yes it will.  Setting `setFrom` to an email address other than one that passes SPF will cause it to be marked as **PISHED**.  I am assuming gmail or hotmail do not list your server as an allowed server.  I would recommend you use as service like http://mail-tester.com to trouble shoot.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this working is to create an email address on your website (me@mysite.com) then get the website to automatically forward all mail to your gmail account. Then, use the website email address in the 'From' and 'Reply-To' address of your mail() routine.